# Eventbus: How to deal with no clear unsubscribe point?

Tags: android, android-broadcast, greenrobot-eventbus

### Broad Problem

How do you deal with situations where there is no clear place to unsubscribe?

#### Specific Problem

In a BroadcastReceiver in Android, there's no end-of-lifecycle method where one can call EventBus's unsubscribe. This BroadcastReceiver can be called multiple times. Since there was no unregister, the event triggers exponentially (actually arithmetically) more actions after the first event, since we're registering again in the initialization method (onReceive).

I'm guessing this situation is common enough to discuss this here.

### Potential Solutions

We're checking if there are existing subscribers for a particular event and only then registering on to the bus when there are no subscribers.

This seems to be hackish and an unreliable method. Case in point, what if another part of the code starts relying on the same event and that too has to be registered? We'll already have a subscriber on the bus from the new location and our old code won't register itself. Our logic will fail or will have to become more complex and tightly coupled with number of subscribers, etc.

Please point out if the problem is not easily understandable, I'll perhaps try a different way of explaining this.

Comment: Also, I quite didn't understand what greenrobot said on the issue tracker: "Broadcast receivers are typically too short lived for EventBus to be useful." What does this mean?
Our BCRs receive the intent and do downloads and network calls (long running events) is this a bad pattern?

Comment: Well, what kind of event do you need to pass to your BCR ? I mean, a BCR would typically send events, not receive them.

Comment: @Gordak BCRs receive events :). We're handling push notifications on this BCR that we're talking about

Comment: Well, of course BCR receive events (System wide or between applications), but you would typically send events locally (through EventBus) . My bad if it was not clear. What I mean is that the BCR will typically live for a very short time. To quote Android developers : 
"A BroadcastReceiver object is only valid for the duration of the call to onReceive(Context, Intent). Once your code returns from this function, the system considers the object to be finished and no longer active."

Hence, it's not really relevant to subscribe a BCR to events... As it is very unlikely to receive any event at all.

Comment: @Gordak I must be using a funny pattern there. I want to use onEventAsync (for threading) so I'm subscribing the BCR. Would you suggest a workaround to achieve the same thing - running something in a bg thread from BCR using EventBus?; I don't prefer Asynctasks, raw threads or managing threadpools manually; also Android-bolt and other threading libs will be an overkill for what I need here. Subscribe a POJO?

Answer (score 1):

Broadcast receivers are created by Android to handle one broadcast. They run on the main thread which also handles the UI. So, they should run very quickly and definitely not do any long running tasks or accessing the network.

Given that, it does not make sense for them to register with an event bus at all.

Instead, your broadcast receiver should just start some work on an Android service, which, having a defined life cycle, is a good candidate to register with an event bus.

Comment: We've a BCR to handle push notifications. So we might be many notifications in the same minute. We're using EventBus's `onEventAsync` to execute all of these, so there's no problem of it blocking the MainThread. Services seem like an overkill when all we need is another thread. Does this sound okay?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let me answer here.

First :

> This BroadcastReceiver can be called multiple times. Since there was
>   no unregister, the event triggers exponentially (actually
>   arithmetically) more actions after the first event

I don't know which EventBus you use. But **if the EventBus holds a strong reference to your subscriber, then you are going to have memory leaks if you can't unsubscribe**. It may also be the reason your BCR registers multiple times, because the instance is not actually destroyed (but should be) after its `onReceive` method has been called (just a theory, to be confirmed).

If you have to perform a long task once you receive something in your BCR, start a [Service](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/components/services.html). The Service will run as long as its task is not finished (actually, you can also let it handle its own lifecycle). **A `Service` is designed to live a long as it serves a purpose and is a good candidate to subscribe to a EventBus, because it actually has a lifecycle defined**, which means you can easily subscribe and unsubscribe.

I'm not sure to understand your problem related to :

> This seems to be hackish and an unreliable method. Case in point, what
>   if another part of the code starts relying on the same event and that
>   too has to be registered? We'll already have a subscriber on the bus
>   from the new location and our old code won't register itself.

Comment: I'm using the greenrobot eventbus: https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus . That's a good suggestion: use service because it has a clear unreg point due a proper lifecycle. This issue is because the eventbus is shared across components not because of a strong reference.